# The word 'Pussy Riot', In russian foreign minister interview

Tags: meaning-in-context

> CNN's Christiane Amanpour asked Russian Foreign Minister Sergey Lavrov in an interview to comment on the state of the U.S. presidential election. She ended up getting a bit more than she bargained for when she prefaced the question with a reference to the Russian punk band 'Pussy Riot.'
>
> Short transcript of the exchange:
>
> AMANPOUR: Can I just try one last question? One last question. A bit cheeky but I'm going to ask you. Russia had its own Pussy Riot moment. What do you think of Donald Trump’s pussy riot moment?
>
> LAVROV: Well, I don't know what this would… English is not my mother tongue, I don't know if I would sound decent. There are so many pussies around the presidential campaign on both sides that I prefer not to comment on this.
>
> Source: [Russia's FM Leaves Amanpour Speechless, 'So Many Pussies' on Both Sides of U.S. Election](http://www.haaretz.com/world-news/u-s-election-2016/1.747244)

I dont know if you heared about Russian Foreign minister when he was asked

What does she meant by Pussy Riot ?. I did checked some SO questions about the usage of word pussy. (Could be a cat for example) but my main question the meaning of her question.

Comment: Pussy Riot is the name of a  rock band.

Comment: [Pussy Riot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pussy_Riot).  Not really a question about English, more a cultural event.  To understand the context please read the linked Wikipedia article.

Comment: @andrew so amnpour was saying russia is being like the feminist rock band ?

Comment: No, when we say "(noun) moment", we mean "a moment or event that had to do with (noun)".  Exactly what that means depends heavily on context, but in this case it probably means "an incident that had to do with Pussy Riot".  By the way, I doubt she literally asked, "Russia had its own Pussy Riot moment?" because that looks like a statement, not a question.

Comment: What is your English language question? "Pussy Riot" is a name (being capitalized if for no other reason) and not a word. The usage has to do with current affairs in context.  Also, why did you not capitalize it in your title? It is misleading.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English.

Comment: This is a valid question about English usage for someone learning the language, in my opinion. If it weren't for stangdon's follow-up comment (incorporated into my answer below), I would have no idea what was meant by Christiane Amanpour's comment either. How else would someone learning English come to understand the sentences in question? I think we should cut @moudiz (and other learners) some slack when it comes to unusual topical usage that is confusing even to native speakers.

Comment: I think this is a valid question and I would vote to keep it open.  While the question involves current events, it's also about understanding the multiple senses in which the individual words are used, and about what "(noun) moment" means.

Comment: Always include a larger portion of the text and a link whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "CNN's Christiane Amanpour asked Russian Foreign Minister Sergey Lavrov in an interview to comment on the state of the U.S. presidential election. She ended up getting a bit more than she bargained for when she prefaced the question with a reference to the Russian punk band 'Pussy Riot.'
>   Short transcript of the exchange:
>   AMANPOUR: Can I just try one last question? One last question. A bit cheeky but I'm going to ask you. Russia had its own Pussy Riot moment. What do you think of Donald Trump’s pussy riot moment?
>
> "LAVROV: Well, I don't know what this would… English is not my mother tongue, I don't know if I would sound decent. There are so many pussies around the presidential campaign on both sides that I prefer not to comment on this.
>   read more: http://www.haaretz.com/world-news/u-s-election-2016/1.747244"

"Seeing the transcript, I can now address it more clearly. Amanpour is making a play on words. Russia had an incident involving the band Pussy Riot: a literal "Pussy Riot" moment. Donald Trump also recently had an incident involving the word "pussy", which caused a great uproar: a metaphorical "riot about the word 'pussy'" moment."

(All credit for this analysis goes to @stangdon with my thanks.)

Comment: Seeing the transcript, I can now address it more clearly.  Amanpour is making a play on words.  Russia had an incident involving the band Pussy Riot: a literal "Pussy Riot" moment.  Donald Trump also recently had an incident involving the word "pussy", which caused a great uproar: a metaphorical "riot about the word 'pussy'" moment.

Comment: It's a play on words, but once you understand the reference it's not at all obscure.

Comment: @Andrew - Understanding plays on words can be deceptively difficult for a non-native speaker. What seems intuitive to us can be very difficult to grasp for them.

Comment: @J.R. fair enough.